# Messages with attachments are always focused

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

We running some tests with Office365 and on our tests, all Messages with attachments are always focused.

Even if a new disposable mail account, sending for the first time an email that looks like spam, but has an attachment, are coming as focused.

Is this intentional or some kind of bug?

Below has one example of the received mail from a disposable mail which is the first time receiving from this contact an email.

```
{
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"CQAAABYAAADvXUbzI/ANT5/mbNYK1U88AAEXl851\"",
    "id": "AAMkADljZjJjNTY0LTIxMTgtNDE5OC1hZDU4LTYxYzZkYjE5YjVlNwBGAAAAAAByYbgd0O6zQa-ENbQosyJcBwDvXUbzI-ANT5-mbNYK1U88AAAAAAEMAADvXUbzI-ANT5-mbNYK1U88AAEXdUI-AAA=",
    "createdDateTime": "2017-06-21T16:39:54Z",
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-06-21T16:39:54Z",
    "changeKey": "CQAAABYAAADvXUbzI/ANT5/mbNYK1U88AAEXl851",
    "categories": [],
    "receivedDateTime": "2017-06-21T16:39:54Z",
    "sentDateTime": "2017-06-21T16:39:44Z",
    "hasAttachments": true,
    "internetMessageId": "<351eb7b7648da421105710a88bcb18ade625@guerrillamail.com>",
    "subject": "Test Disposable Mail with Attachment",
    "bodyPreview": "Mail with attachment from a disposable mail.\n\n\n\n\n\n----\nSent using Guerrillamail.com\nBlock or report abuse: https://www.guerrillamail.com//abuse/?a=T05gBAMBR7kchi6y8XALdwfTA8We395T1atRc9niRQcxVA%3D%3D",
    "importance": "normal",
    "parentFolderId": "AQMkADljZjJjNTY0LTIxMQA4LTQxOTgtYWQ1OC02MWM2ZGIxOWI1ZTcALgAAA3JhuB3Q7rNBr8Q1tCizIlwBAO9dRvMj8A1Pn_Zs1grVTzwAAAIBDAAAAA==",
    "conversationId": "AAQkADljZjJjNTY0LTIxMTgtNDE5OC1hZDU4LTYxYzZkYjE5YjVlNwAQAOeWG0KriC1NovfYGMqEpnU=",
    "isDeliveryReceiptRequested": null,
    "isReadReceiptRequested": false,
    "isRead": false,
    "isDraft": false,
    "webLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/owa/?ItemID=AAMkADljZjJjNTY0LTIxMTgtNDE5OC1hZDU4LTYxYzZkYjE5YjVlNwBGAAAAAAByYbgd0O6zQa%2FENbQosyJcBwDvXUbzI%2FANT5%2FmbNYK1U88AAAAAAEMAADvXUbzI%2FANT5%2FmbNYK1U88AAEXdUI%2FAAA%3D&exvsurl=1&viewmodel=ReadMessageItem",
    "inferenceClassification": "focused",
    "body": {
        "contentType": "text",
        "content": "Mail with attachment from a disposable mail.\n\n\n\n\n\n----\nSent using Guerrillamail.com\nBlock or report abuse: https://www.guerrillamail.com//abuse/?a=T05gBAMBR7kchi6y8XALdwfTA8We395T1atRc9niRQcxVA%3D%3D\n"
    },
    "sender": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "82mg3t+6g7ctur4zz01o@guerrillamail.com",
            "address": "82mg3t+6g7ctur4zz01o@guerrillamail.com"
        }
    },
    "from": {
        "emailAddress": {
            "name": "82mg3t+6g7ctur4zz01o@guerrillamail.com",
            "address": "82mg3t+6g7ctur4zz01o@guerrillamail.com"
        }
    },
    "toRecipients": [
        {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "Average Joe",
                "address": "myAddress@myDomain.onmicrosoft.com"
            }
        }
    ],
    "ccRecipients": [],
    "bccRecipients": [],
    "replyTo": []
}
```

And here how I see in Outlook:

[image]

Tried to find the contact, without success:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts?$filter=emailAddresses/any(a:a/address eq '82mg3t+6g7ctur4zz01o@guerrillamail.com')` give me:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('197126e9-151f-4c9c-ac03-77a479f8de60')/contacts",
    "value": []
}
```

So the contact should not be ranked or anything like that (not seeing in the `people` endpoint too).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay, but I wanted to discuss this with the devs to get a better understanding. I'm not 100% positive, but I think what you're saying (since you tagged this with `microsoftgraph`) is that these messages have the `inferenceClassification` property set to `focused`?

If these messages have a [modern attachment](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Video-Smarter-attachments-1640e4ed-5322-4145-8798-cbf16ca3773e?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) (i.e. the sender attached as a OneDrive file), then the message will always be focused for the recipient.

If the message has a normal attachment, then it is not expected that they would always be focused. If this is the case for you, it may be that the messages are focused for another reason. We'd have to take a look at the messages themselves to tell for sure.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I've updated the question with more details and an example. The attachment wasn't a modern attachment, was a simple PNG image.

Comment: Ok. Can you reach out to me on Twitter? I'd like to get some more info from you offline. @JasonJohMSFT